# ngClass applying CSS while ignoring condition when page loads

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I am loading a `todos` list, every `todo` has a flag field which if `true` the `ng-class` should apply. When loading data into the page `ng-class` is applied regardless and the text shows decorated, while it should only if `isCompleted=true`.

Th problem occurs only at the first load, because after wards I can use the checkboxes properly and `ng-class` works just fine when I play with it.

**AngularJS**

```
<ul id="todo-list">
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{completed: todo.isCompleted}" class="editing">
                <div class="view" >
                    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" ng-change="" ng-model="todo.isCompleted" ng-checked="{{todo.isCompleted}}">
                    <label ng-hide="isEditing" ng-dblclick="isEditing = !isEditing">{{todo.title}}</label>
                    <button class="destroy" ng-click="remove(todo)"></button>
                </div>
                <input class="edit" ng-show="isEditing" ng-model="todo.title" ng-blur="isEditing = !isEditing;edit(todo);">
        </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.completed {
    color: #a9a9a9;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you also post the code of a controller?

Comment: Can only assume its set to true on load unless you post your controller code

Comment: What's the initial value of those items? That code should work if their initial value is not set or false.

Comment: I debugged and all todos get loaded with isComplete = false. In fact the checkbox not being tick works, but not the ng-class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot ' '

```
ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted==true}"
```

Comment: It behaves the same way regardless.

Comment: your todo.isCompleted is string or boolean ?
if its string use todo.isCompleted=='true'

Comment: @DaniëlSmink there is nothing shown in Doc regarding conditional class with ng-class.

Comment: @squiroid I will try it, but where you mean? in all the conditions on the page?

Comment: not page in ng-class itself is your todo.isComplete is boolean or string value?

Comment: Is a boolean, in the controller treating it as boolean works just fine. So you mean ng-class="{completed: 'todo.isCompleted'}"?

Comment: Sorry guys this solution worked. I haven't noticed that you wrote ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted==true}" while I wrote ng-class="{'completed': todo.isCompleted}". So is like there was no condition. Thanks!

Comment: I was referring to the quotes ('') from before you edited the post to include ==true squiroid. I agree that there is nothing in the documentation about conditionals.

Comment: Still @DaniëlSmink quotes are required to mention the name of the class you want to added.

Comment: Quotes around the class name is not required when the class name is singular. In case you use a dash in your class name then you are correct in stating that it needs quotes :)